# Solr documents composed of both JSON and XML?

Tags: xml, json, solr

I want to index files generated by a webapp using Solr.

Some data in each document is generated by the client in JSON and some is generated by the server in XML. Solr supports both these formats, but it seems to only support overwriting a document when updating, whereas I need to merge the two halves of the document together.

Converting between JSON and XML with a library like Jackson seems like too much error-prone work. At first I thought such conversion might implement useful validation or schema versioning, but really it seems not.

Is there any easy way to combine data from the frontend and backend, without conversion? Should I be leery of sending JSON directly from the browser to Solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid some programatic work in merging the XML and JSON data in some way. Because as you said, SOLR overwrites a document when you commit with the same doc ID.

The easiest would be to use [SOLRJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) and read in (and parse) the two data types and then write to the SOLR index only once.